# Props gets updated 3 times in single refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am new in react.I am trying to use react-redux style from the beginning.
Below is what I tried for a simple product listing page.

In my App.js for checking if the user is still logged in.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (isUserAuthenticated() === true) {
      const token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwt');
      if (token) {
        agent.setToken(token);
      }
      this.props.appLoad(token ? token : null, this.props.history);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
      <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        isUserAuthenticated() === true
          ? <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect to='/logout' />
      )} />
    )

    return (

      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            {routes.map((route, idx) =>
              route.ispublic ?
                <Route path={route.path} component={withLayout(route.component)} key={idx} />
                :
                <PrivateRoute path={route.path} component={withLayout(route.component)} key={idx} />
            )}
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStatetoProps, { appLoad })(App));
```

In my action.js appLoaded action is as under

```
export const appLoad = (token, history) => {
    return {
        type: APP_LOAD,
        payload: { token, history }
    }
}
```

reducer.js for it

```
import { APP_LOAD, APP_LOADED, APP_UNLOADED, VARIFICATION_FAILED } from './actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    appName: 'Etsync',
    token: null,
    user: null,
    is_logged_in: false
}

const checkLogin = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case APP_LOAD:
            state = {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload,
                is_logged_in: false
            }
            break;

        case APP_LOADED:
            state = {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload.user,
                token: action.payload.user.token,
                is_logged_in: true
            }
            break;
        case APP_UNLOADED:
            state = initialState
            break;
        case VARIFICATION_FAILED:
            state = {
                ...state,
                user: null,
            }
            break;
        default:
            state = { ...state };
            break;
    }
    return state;
}

export default checkLogin;
```

And in Saga.js I have watched every appLoad action and performed the operation as under

```
import { takeEvery, fork, put, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { APP_LOAD } from './actionTypes';
import { appLoaded, tokenVerificationFailed } from './actions';
import { unsetLoggeedInUser } from '../../helpers/authUtils';
import agent from '../agent';
function* checkLogin({ payload: { token, history } }) {
    try {
        let response = yield call(agent.Auth.current, token);
        yield put(appLoaded(response));
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message) {
            unsetLoggeedInUser();
            yield put(tokenVerificationFailed());
            history.push('/login');
        } else if (error.response.text === 'Unauthorized') {
            unsetLoggeedInUser();
            yield put(tokenVerificationFailed());
        }
    }
}

export function* watchUserLogin() {
    yield takeEvery(APP_LOAD, checkLogin)
}

function* commonSaga() {
    yield all([fork(watchUserLogin)]);
}

export default commonSaga;
```

After that for productLists page my code is as under

```
//importing part

class EcommerceProductEdit extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        **//seeing the props changes**
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.activateAuthLayout();
        if (this.props.user !== null && this.props.user.shop_id)
            this.props.onLoad({
                payload: Promise.all([
                    agent.Products.get(this.props.user),
                ])
            });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            // JSX code removed for making code shorter
        );
    }
}

const mapStatetoProps = state => {
    const { user, is_logged_in } = state.Common;
    const { products } = state.Products.products.then(products => {
                    return products;
    });
    return { user, is_logged_in, products };
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, { activateAuthLayout, onLoad })(EcommerceProductEdit);
```

But in this page in componentDidMount if I log the props, I get it three time in the console. as under

[image: Console image]

Rest everything is working fine. I am just concerned,the code i am doing is not up to the mark.
Any kinds of insights are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have three state updates happening in ways that can't batch the render.

You first render with no data. You can see this in the first log. There is no user, and they are not logged in.
Then you get a user. You can see this in the second log. There is a user, but they are not logged in.
Then you log them in. You can see this in the third log. There is a user, and they are logged in.

If these are all being done in separate steps and update the Redux store each step you'll render in between each step. If you however got the user, and logged them in, and then stored them in the redux state in the same time frame you'd only render an additional time. Remember React and Redux are heavily Async libraries that try to use batching to make sure things done in the same time frame only cause one render, but sometimes you have multiple network steps that need to be processed at the same time. So no you're not doing anything wrong, you just have a lot of steps that can't easily be put into the same frame because they rely on some outside resource that has its own async fetch.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. But is there some way this could be done in one time frame as you said ?

Comment: You'd have to make modifications to your saga and first mount so that instead of loading the app if there is a token, it attempts to log the user in

Comment: I was trying but got confused for what should i actually do.
I have checked if user is logged in in app's conponentdidmount, and then from there app load action is dispatched and caught by saga, then, after check the saga is dispatching the app loaded action and updating the state.
Where should I escape the step to achieve as you suggested ?